How to Exclude Specific Files (like .properties),some local files from GitHub Copilot in IntelliJ IDEA?
How to prevent GitHub Copilot to scan some local files which aren't pushed to remote repository in IntelliJ IDEA?
I have no idea of it, because the files don't exist in remote repository and there some authentication password existed in these files, I want copilot to avoid analyzing these files. The following way can't resolve this issue
https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/managing-github-copilot-in-your-organization/configuring-content-exclusions-for-github-copilot

Appears that you need a business license to configure exclusions. Unless you are referring to git tracking changes in your local repository?
